# The 'datePublished' property and the HTML 'lang' attribute

Tags: html, date, locale, microdata

I was just adding some Microdata to my page and started wondering if the `lang` attribute affects the [Schema.org `datePublished` property](http://schema.org/datePublished).

I've added the following to my HTML tag:

```
<html lang="nl">
```

When I do:

```
<h5 itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-11-30UTC12:00:00">Nov 30th 2015 12:00am</h5>
```

it's not written like we do in the Netherlands. We write it like `d-m-Y`. Do I have to write my `datePublished` property like that too? How do search engines pick that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microdata doesn’t use the `lang` attribute.

And in HTML5+Microdata, you can’t use the `content` attribute on an `h5` element (only on the `meta` element).

If you want to provide a date, you should use [HTML5’s `time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) (or [`meta`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) if it shouldn’t be visible on the page). The `time` element allows you to provide the machine-readable format in the `datetime` attribute.

For your example, it could look like:

```html
<h5>
  <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-11-30T12:00:00Z">Nov 30th 2015 12:00am</time>
</h5>
```